# Student Data not reflecting in Database, even though Database is Initiated. Please

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

```
//data-source.ts file
import "reflect-metadata"
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import { ormConfig } from "./ormconfig";
import { Student } from "./entity/Student";


export const AppDataSource = new DataSource(ormConfig)


// to initialize the initial connection with the database, register all entities
// and "synchronize" database schema, call "initialize()" method of a newly created database
// once in your application bootstrap
// console.log("DB is going to be initiated...");

AppDataSource.initialize().then( async () => {

    // here you can start to work with your database
    console.log("DB is initiated...");
       
    const student = new Student()
    student.id = 1
    student.firstName = "Test Student"
    student.lastName = "LastName."

    // student.academicDetails.cpi = 6.58
    // student.educationHistory.tcNumber = 123

    // await AppDataSource.manager.save(Student)
    // console.log("Saved the Student with id : " + student.id)

    // const studentInsert = await AppDataSource.manager.insert(Student, {})

    // const students = await AppDataSource.manager.find(Student)
    // console.log("Loaded Students : ", students)

    const studentRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(Student)
    await studentRepository.save(student) 
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))


export default {AppDataSource}
```

And this is my Student.routes.ts file

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction, Router } from "express";
import pathConstant from "../environments/constants";
import { AppDataSource } from "../handlers/db/data-source";
import { Student } from "../handlers/db/entity/Student";

const routesStudent = Router();

// Student Get Request defined here -->
routesStudent.get (
    `${pathConstant.pathPrefixStudent}/app`,
    async function (req : Request, res : Response)  {
        const student = await AppDataSource.manager.save(Student)
        // const studentInsert = await AppDataSource.manager.insert(Student, {})
        const students = await AppDataSource.manager.find(Student)
        return res.json({message : "Student get response works...",
                         data : students
    })
    }
)
```

I am trying to insert data in students table , but am unable to do the same. Database is being initiated properly. How do I insert the data as you can see it is mostly hardcoded..The table is created but the entries are not getting feeded.

Comment: It looks like you are reading the data before `AppDataSource.initialize().then(...)` is done. When in doubt make a minimal reproducible example and add more console logs